# Show that $A = 0$ using Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

> If $A \in  M_n(\Bbb C)$ is such that $(Ax, x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb C^n$, then show that $A = 0$.
>
> Show that the above result is false in $\Bbb C$ is replaced by $\Bbb R$.

I know how to prove it algebraically.I also know that if I take the rotation operator then $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ will serve as a counter-example in case of $\Bbb R$.

I want to show the above fact geometrically.

SO TWO QUESTIONS ARE:

- Why does not the result become false if I take a rotation in $\Bbb C$?
- Why does the result hold in case of $\Bbb C$ ?How to prove it geometrically?

Comment: What is $(Ax,x)$? Inner product?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri,yes

Comment: Okay. `\langle`,`\rangle` give angular braces

Comment: For your first question, this is because every rotation $A$ over $\mathbb C$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis. You can evaluate $(Ax,x)$ with each eigenvector $x$ to see that $Ax=0$. Rotations over $\mathbb R$ don't have a full eigenbasis in general and so this trick fails.

Comment: @user1551,I am not getting it,my question is what happens when we do rotation in C

Comment: As said in my previous comment, rotations over $\mathbb C$ are not like rotations over $\mathbb R$. E.g. A rotation $Q\in SO_2(\mathbb R)$ does not leave any vector invariant, but this is not the case over $\mathbb C$. If $x$ is an eigenvector of $Q\in SO_2(\mathbb C)$, $Q$ will **not** rotate everything. Rather, it maps the eigenvector $x$ to $ix$ or $-ix$. Hence you don't have $(Qx,x)=0$.

Comment: @user1551,see I dont want a justification using eigenvectors or anything like that.Pls understand my point

Comment: @user1551,if we rotate in $\Bbb R$ by $90$ the rotation the angle between the vectors in the new system and in original system is $90$ ,why it does not happen in $C$

Comment: I don't understand your question. How do you define the angle of rotation when the inner product between a vector and its "rotated" image is not necessarily real?